# npx create-react-app fails with error "cannot find module block-stream

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

$ npx create-react-app counter
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'block-stream'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\theop\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\tar\lib\entry-writer.js
- C:\Users\theop\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\tar\lib\pack.js
- C:\Users\theop\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\tar\tar.js
- C:\Users\theop\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\tar-pack\index.js
- C:\Users\theop\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js
- C:\Users\theop\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (C:\Users\theop\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\tar\lib\entry-writer.js:7:19)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  'C:\Users\theop\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\tar\lib\entry-writer.js',
  'C:\Users\theop\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\tar\lib\pack.js',
  'C:\Users\theop\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\tar\tar.js',
  'C:\Users\theop\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\tar-pack\index.js',
  'C:\Users\theop\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js',
  'C:\Users\theop\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js'
  ]
  }

Answer (score 0):

I thought you installed block-stream first

```
npm init && npm i block-stream && npx create-react-app counter
```

or using [vite](https://vitejs.dev/)

```
npm create vite@latest my-vue-app -- --template react
```

Comment: I installed block-stream. Still got the same error.